# histbase in plot() fails to use an input value

Tags: pine-script

```
strategy("Test", overlay=true)

p0 = input.price(defval = 0, title = "Initial Price", confirm = true, inline = "start")

plot(p0, color = color.green)
plot(close, "Test", color = color.new(color.orange, 60), style = plot.style_area, histbase = p0)
```

This plots an area with histbase 0, even though p0 is set to a meaningful price. If you hardcode the exact same value, e.g. `histbase = 2100.0`, then it plots correctly. Is histbase not designed for non-hardcoded values?

Comment: Looks like a bug, reported to TradingView support.